# Set default email or other address to get feedback from user

Tags: java, android, feedback

I am trying to set default email address where the feedback from the my android application will be stored and I could get them to read. However, I am not able to do it.Also, could you suggest me other better ways to store feedback from user of your app which I could read later?

Here is my code:

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/feedback"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:text="@string/feedback"
        android:textColor="#26A69A" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

**feedback.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#D0ECE7  "
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="54dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:text="@string/ftitle"
        android:textColor="#26A69A"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/feed"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="62dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Write Here"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textColor="#26A69A"
        android:textColorLink="#26A69A" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/send"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/fSend"
            android:textColor="#26A69A" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cancel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/fCancel"
            android:textColor="#26A69A" />

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.abina.feedback;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Dialog thisDialog;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //for feedback
        Button feedback  = findViewById(R.id.feedback);

        feedback.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                thisDialog =  new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
                thisDialog.show();
                thisDialog.setContentView(R.layout.feedback);
                thisDialog.setTitle("Send Your Feedback");
                thisDialog.getWindow().setDimAmount(0.5f);
                EditText editText = thisDialog.findViewById(R.id.editText);
                Button send = thisDialog.findViewById(R.id.send);
                Button cancel = thisDialog.findViewById(R.id.cancel);
                editText.setEnabled(true);
                send.setEnabled(true);
                cancel.setEnabled(true);


                send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Your message is sent.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        thisDialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
                cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        thisDialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Strings.xml**

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">feedback</string>
    <string name="feedback">Send us your Recomendation and feedback.</string>
    <string name="ftitle">Recomendation</string>
    <string name="feed">We are glad to have you. Please send us your feedback and suggestions to improve this application and make it easier for other to use.</string>
    <string name="fSend">Send</string>
    <string name="fCancel">Cancel</string>
</resources>
```

Comment: *I am not able to do it* -- why not

Comment: I tried to use: Intent browser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND, Uri.parse("myemailaddress@gmail.com"));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to send e-mail to you via e-mail app. In this case you can get users feedback from your editText and pass it instead of "body of email"

```
send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
            i.setType("message/rfc822");
            i.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{"test@gmail.com"});
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Feedback");
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , "body of email");
            try {
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail..."));
            } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "There are no email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            thisDialog.cancel();
        }
    });
```

And I recommend to use AlertDialog.Builder instead of Dialog.

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution is to have a `TextView` in a `Navigation Drawer` or in an `About activity` with theses attributes:

```
android:autoLink="email"
android:text="youremail@host.com"
```

With this the user can just click on your email and the mail app will start...  
 As for the other part make sure you don't give out your personal email. 
 Better use a professional email or an email specifically for the app.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this to fetch feedback with device information.

```
feedback.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                 sendFeedback();
      }
    });


    public void sendFeedback() {
    String body = null;
    try {
      body = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0).versionName;
      body = "\n\n--------------\n" +
          "Please don't remove this information" +
          "\n Device OS: Android " +
          "\n Device OS Version: " + Build.VERSION.RELEASE + "" +
          "\n App Version: " + body + "" +
          "\n Device Brand: " + Build.BRAND + "" +
          "\n Device Model: " + Build.MODEL + "" +
          "\n Device Manufacturer: " + Build.MANUFACTURER;
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {

    }
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("message/rfc822");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"test@gmail.com"});
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "App Subject");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body);
    startActivity(
        Intent.createChooser(intent, getString(R.string.choose_email_client)));
  }
```